# How to get latest record with same ID ?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to get latest record from the SQL datatable. 
I have following data table. 
but its returning 0 records.

Table1

```
PKID----FKID-----------CDateTime
1        25     2012-11-19 17:51:22.000
2        25     2012-11-19 17:53:22.000
3        25     2012-11-19 17:54:22.000
4        26     2012-11-19 17:55:22.000
5        26     2012-11-19 17:56:22.000
```

Now,  I want the latest record which have FKID 25 Its supposed to return 3rd record (PKID =3)
...How to get that ? 
I have written the below code but its returning nothing.

```
SELECT * from Table1 WHERE FKID = 25
 and CDateTime= (select max(CDateTime) From Table1 )
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select top 1 * from tablename where FKID = 25 order by CDateTime desc
```

Comment: What does top 1 means?

Answer (score 3):

The Problem you have is that you are putting an `AND` constraint which will never be true, Hence you are not getting any output.
This query will do the trick.

```
 SELECT * from Table1 WHERE FKID = 25
     and CDateTime= (select max(CDateTime) From Table1 where FKID = 25 )
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution to this problem is joining itself on a subquery which gets the lastest date for each `FKID`.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT FKID, MAX(CDATETIME) maxDate
            FROM tableName
            GROUP BY FKID
        ) b ON a.FKID = b.FKID AND
                a.CDateTime = MaxDate
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26c5a/1)

OR by using `Common Table Expression`

```
WITH latestRecords 
AS
(
    SELECT PKID, FKID, CDATETime,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FKID
                        ORDER BY CDateTime DESC) rn
    FROM TableNAme
)
SELECT PKID, FKID, CDATETime
FROM latestRecords
WHERE rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26c5a/2)

Answer (score 1):

your query is not returning value because the sub query (select max(CDateTime) From Table1 )
will give you the maximum CDateTime from the whole table not for FKID = 25

try this:

```
with cte as(
SELECT *,row_number() over (partition by FKID order by CDateTime desc) as rn 
from Table1 )
select * from cte 
WHERE FKID = 25
and rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT * from Table1 WHERE FKID = 25
and CDateTime= (select max(CDateTime) From Table1 where FKID = 25)
```